# How to send email while keeping the To: list blank and only Bcc: list populated using sendmail function of smtplib in python

Tags: python, sendmail, smtplib

I am new to Python. I have a case where I need to send email where the `Bcc:` list must be populated and `To:` list must be blank in order to hide the recipients identity.

I gave `msg['TO']`as `''`, `None`, `['']`, `[]`. None of these worked.

I Googled, but found nothing related to my problem. I kept `To:` list blank in my code and some email ids in `Bcc:` list, then ran my code and got the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\script.py", line 453, in send_notification
    smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 742, in sendmail
    raise SMTPRecipientsRefused(senderrs)
SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'': (555, '5.5.2 Syntax error. hb1sm19555493pbd.36 - gsmtp')}
```

Following is my code:

```
msg['From'] = send_from
msg['To'] = ''
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['BCC'] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
```

Comment: Did you try omitting the TO-field altogether?

Comment: `del msg['To']` perhaps.

Comment: Yes,  I tried commenting `msg['To']` . Still it gave the same error.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I'm pretty sure all emails are required to have a `To` address.</strike> (Edit: [Actually, they're not](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6))

Whenever I receive emails that were sent to an anonymized list like what you're describing, the `To` and `From` addresses are generally both the same, which is a reasonable workaround. It looks pretty clean to the recipient:

```
To: some-student-org@my-university.edu
From: some-student-org@my-university.edu
Bcc: me
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `bcc` using python's `smtplib`, don't include the `bcc` header, just include the `bcc` recipients in the call to `smtplib.sendmail`. For your specific example:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

smtp_server = 'localhost'
send_from = 'your@email.com'
send_to = ['one@email.com', 'two@email.com']
msg_subject = 'test'
msg_text = 'hello'

msg = MIMEText(msg_text)
msg['Subject'] = msg_subject
msg['From'] = send_from
smtp = smtplib.SMTP()
smtp.connect(smtp_server)
smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())
smtp.quit()
```